# PDFtoTEXT not converting UTF-8 encoded text completely, especially the accented characters

Tags: unix, pdftotext, xpdf

I am working on a project which requires to convert PDF to text. The PDF contains Hindi fonts (Mangal to be specific) along with English.

100% of english is getting converted into text. The conversion of Hindi part is around 95%. Remaining 5% Hindi text is either coming as **blank or like " ा"**. I could figure out that the accented characters are not getting converted to text properly.

I am using following code:

```
pdftotext -enc UTF-8 pdfname.pdf textname.txt
```

The PDF uses following Fonts

**name, type,   emb,    sub,    uni**

ZDPKEY+Mangal,  CID TrueType,   yes,    yes,    yes

Mangal  TrueType,   no, no, no

Helvetica-Bold  Type 1, no, no, no

CODUBM+Mangal-Bold, CID TrueType,   yes,    yes,    yes

Mangal-Bold,    TrueType,   no, no, no

Times-Roman,    Type 1  no, no, no

Helvetica,  Type 1, no, no, no

Following is the result of conversion. Left side is original PDF. Right side is text opened in notepad:

```
http://preview.tinyurl.com/qbxud9o
```

My questions is whether the 5% missing / junk characters be correctly captured in Text with open-source packages? Would appreciate your inputs!

Comment: Is it a scanned pdf? Are you sure the missing characters are present in the pdf file as text? Maybe the OCR didn't detect those characters in the first place.

Comment: Hi Samik: It is not a scanned PDF. It is a "generated" PDF. All characters are present in the PDF. I can copy same and paste in notepad.

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to.

```
pdftotext -enc "UTF-8" pdfname.pdf textname.txt
```

It has worked for me, similarly it should work for you.